# What effect does programmatically reinstalling an application have on it's task stack?

Tags: android, android-task

If I have an application called 'merchant app' that downloads an update .apk file for itself and then launches a middle man 'updater app' to install this update, will the installation process clear the task stack associated with the merchant app?

I'm asking to determine what Intent flags I might include when relaunching the merchant app from the updater app. Currently I'm thinking of adding

`FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`

but if the reinstall process clears all merchant app associated tasks then I don't think I'd need any flags, right?

Comment: The whole stack will be cleared.

Comment: yes it will since the app process will be terminated.